# Excel Powerpivot using CUBE formulae in conjunction with Data Validation

Tags: excel, powerpivot, validation

I've searched the internets for this, and drawn a blank, so thought I'd try for an anwer here.

Basically, I'm trying to generate a Data Validation List which references members of a column in a table stored in Powerpivot. I know that CUBESET will store the OLAP object in the cell, so I tried creating a formula:

```
=CUBESET("PowerPivot Data","[Core].[Age].Children","Age List")
```

And referencing the cell with that formula. However this just returns a list containing the caption only.

What I'm looking for is a formula that will extract the values from the set and turn them into a range. The other CUBEx functions return a single member or value, but I want to return them in the way =OFFSET would return a reference to a range.

Other methods tried: using Offset, and creating a named range.

I'm trying to avoid using CUBERANKEDMEMBER to generate a list to base my validation on (it would defeat the object really).

Comment: Why not just make a pivot table with one column?  Then you can reference the table in your data validation list.

Comment: Honestly, I could, I'm just wondering if this can be done (i.e. use the members of the CUBESET as a range). Like the CUBERANKEDMEMBER option, it would defeat the object.

Comment: I don't really understand why you think cuberankedmember would defeat the object.  You can use cubesetcount to know exactly how many members there are if you need to.

Comment: "The object" is to be able to use the Members stored in the CUBESET implicitly. Making the Members into an explicit list and then referencing that list would be an extra step. The ideal scenario would be a DATA Validation list formula which contains the cubeset function, or a function which transforms the CUBESET members into a range, but the former doesn't work, and I can't find a way to do the latter.

Comment: Yeah, not sure on that one.  I just make a list using a pivot table or cuberankedmembers.

Comment: Okay, thanks :) May just have to settle for explicit lists myself, but it would be nice to have that automated/in the background, or in general have a way in excel of treating the stored members of a CUBESET as an Excel Range.

Comment: @Soulus101 I know this is a very old topic but I've bumped into this as well and looking for a solution? It would indeed be more elegant to be able to use cubeset.

Comment: @smoens old indeed, and I've only just seen your query. I've come on considerably since I posted this, but as far as I know there is still no way to achieve this.